# pushing a nested array into a nested array angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, http-post

I have a controller that creates a new allegation for a complaint. I can push into the nested (Child table T2), but am not sure why I can't push into a Child table of the child table (T3).

The model in Json look like this:

```
{
"c_ID": 1,
"received_DT": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
"aIO": [{
    "a_ID": 1,
    "c_ID": 9,
    "allegs": [{
        "alleG_ID": 33,
        "Allegation": "Failure..*",
        "disc": []
    }]
}]
```

}

My add angular scope looks as below but I am unsure how I am supposed to push the results.

```
$scope.addAlleg = function () {
        var AIOID = this.a.aiO_ID

        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        var baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";
        $http.post(baseURL + "api/aio/" + AIOID + "/allegs", $scope.newAlleg)
        .then(function (alleg) {
            $scope.c.aIO[0].allegs.push(alleg);
            $scope.newAlleg = {};
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Failed to save new trip" + error;
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.isBusy = false;
        })
    };
```

When I copy the link into postman it posts and creates an allegation just fine, but I know my success/do something with the result is wrong.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost("aio/{aioid}/allegs")]
    public JsonResult Post(int aioid, [FromBody]AllegationsViewModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Map to entity

                var newAllegations = Mapper.Map<ALLEGATIONS>(vm);

                //Save to Database
                _repository.AddAllegations(aioid, newAllegations);

                if (_repository.SaveAll())
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                    return Json(Mapper.Map<AllegationsViewModel>(newAllegations));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Failed to save new allegation", ex);
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Failed to save new allegation");
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(" Validation Failed on new checklist");
    }
```

**I have tried**

```
$scope.c.aIO[0].allegs.push(alleg);
$scope.c.aIO[0].allegs[0].push(alleg);
$scope.c.aIO.allegs.push(alleg);
```

but keep getting bad request.  My add scope to the T2 (1st Child table) works just fine as I have

```
$scope.c.aIO.push(response.data);
```

Also, my html markup looks like this:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="newAlleg.Allegation"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $scope.complaints.aIO[0].allegs.push(alleg.data) ?

I am assuming $scope.c  is $scope.complaints

Comment: I fixed my code to $scope.c, sorry about that. I have tried that, and it still doesn't want to post.

Comment: can you paste here API response ? Looks like its API issue rather than anything.

Comment: Don, could it possibly be my controller if it is working fine on postman?          I couldn't paste my controller here so I edited my question with it.